# Getting {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]} using python-twitter API v1.0

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, python-twitter

I am using python-twitter API v1.0. It says that it works with v1.1 of the twitter API.
This is my code :

```
import json
import urllib2
import urllib
import csv
file1 = open("somez.csv", "wb")
fname="tw1.txt"
file=open(fname,"r")
ins = open( "tw1.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
   array.append( line )
   s = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/' + line[:-1] + '.json'
   print s
   try:

       data=urllib2.urlopen(s)
   except:
       print "Not Found"
    continue
   print data
   json_format=json.load(data)
   js=json_format
   print line[:-1]
   print js[('user')]['id']
   print  js[('user')]['created_at']
   print js['retweet_count']
   print js['text']
#   js = js.decode('utf-8')
   one = line[:-1].encode('utf-8')
   thr = js['user']['id']
   two = js['user']['created_at'].encode('utf-8')
   four = js['retweet_count']
   five = js['text'].encode('utf-8')
   rw =  [one,two,thr,four,five];
   spamWriter = csv.writer(file1 , delimiter=',')
   spamWriter.writerow(rw)
file1.close()
```

I am not able to retrieve any data. It is saying "Not Found". When I open one of the URLs, I get this error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work with the 1.1 API. Get another library.

Comment: You don't use python-twitter in the code provided. You are making requests to the twitter api manually via urllib2.

Comment: @alecxe actually I am authenticating using python-twitter. I have not shown that part because I am able to authenticate and post tweets. Just this part is not working.

Comment: @Jimbo Can you suggest me some other libraries based on python?